# backbonejs , adding view to dom not refreshing the page

Tags: backbone.js, view, refresh, requirejs

I am trying to fix an issue but no luck so far. I am working on a single page app in backbone (1.0) & requirejs (and I am new to backbone). My HTML has 3 divs to show list of departments, list of employees and  details of the employee. When my initial page loads, it shows the list of departments, works fine and so far good. When user clicks on the dept it suppose to display list of employees. Here is my problem , browser doesn't get refreshed.In firebug I am able to see "emplistdiv" is populated correctly. . (A reload of the entire page works fine though)

**my divs**

```
<div class="deptdiv"></div>
<div class="emplistdiv"> </div>
<div class="empdiv"> </div>
```

**router**

```
router.on('route:open', function () {
    var Emplist = new EmpListView();
    Emplist.render();
});
```

**view**

```
var EmpListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.emplistdiv',

 initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            //this.collection.on('reset', this.render); 
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        var emp = new EmpListCollection();
        emp.fetch({                
            success: function(templist) {
                console.log(templist.models.length);
                var temp = _.template($(emptemplate).html(), { emplist: templist.models });
                self.$el.html(temp);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry it was a paste error, i modified the question

Comment: You're saying that the `fetch` succeeds and `templist` has what you expect in it but nothing shows up in the browser? What is `emptemplate` and where is it defined?

Comment: I am using requirejs and I have defined emptemplate. 'define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'models/empListCollection',
        'text!templates/emplisttemplate.html'
    ], function ($, _, Backbone, EmpListCollection, emptemplate) {'

Comment: If `emptemplate` is just some text then you probably want `_.template(emptemplate, ...)` since `$(x).html()` will strip off the outer element of `x` (i.e. `$('<p></p>').html()` is an empty string, not `'<p></p>'`). I'd expect `console.log(temp.models.length)` to raise an exception since `temp` will be `undefined` when you try to `temp.models.length`.

Comment: _.template(emptemplate, ...) appends entire content of the template into the div than html output. My issue is (I assume), once table is added to the div, browser is not getting refreshed.

Comment: Apparently issue was with requirejs caching my javascript files. the code worked fine. Thanks for the help